# Vim vsplit redraw

Tags: vim

Is it possible to redraw vim's screen if I do the following:

1. Vim in small 80x24 terminal
2. `vsplit file2.c`
3. Maximize terminal
4. It's all wonkey and I don't know how to make ti redraw the windows evenly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putty: Refresh VIM screen](http://superuser.com/questions/411093/putty-refresh-vim-screen).  Short version of the answers is to use either Ctrl-L or the `:redraw` command

Comment: @ernie No, it does not (and should not) help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also it is possible set an autocommand to perform `<C-w>=` each time when you resize a terminal.

```
au VimResized * if &equalalways | wincmd = | endif
```

`&equalalways` is an option that resizes windows to equal after splitting / closing (set by default), so it is quite natural to use it here too.

Comment: @user341814 Oh! Yes, indeed. The complexity of local ‘privileges’ system surprises me always.

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> in normal mode to make all windows equally sized.

Answer (score 0):

For correctly adapting non-equal window splits, you can try my [ProportionalResize plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4462).